# How to turn a function into an ASYNC AWAIT

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, components, use-state

Currently, I'm passing a value from a Child Component to a Parent in React.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [callback, setCallback] = useState(null);

    const handleCallback = (childData) => {
        console.log(childData);
        return childData;
    };

    let childDataType = handleCallback();

    if (childDataType === "success") {
        setCallback(true)
    } else if (childDataType === "error") {
        setCallback(true)
    }

    return (
        <div dataValue={dataValue(callback)}/>
    )
}
```

```
const ChildComponent = ({dataValue}) => {
    let callback = thisData[index].value
    return (
        <div dataValue={dataValue(callback)}/>
    )
}
```

I'm trying to use that value to set a state. If the value from the child equals a string then the state is true else false.

Right now I'm able to get the data to `console.log(childData)` inside `handleCallback`. However, the data comes back undefined at first then sets to a value. Because of this, it sets `childDataType` to `undefined`. Which in turn sets my state to undefined.

I need to have the variable `childDataType` to wait for the function to run and return a defined value before trying to set the callback's state. How do I get `handleCallback` to await a defined value before returning its initial value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I like to do is the following

```
  const handleCallback = (childData) => {
       return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          resolve(childData)
       })
    };
```

then u can do

```
 let childDataType = await handleCallback();
```

This is a nice approach because if any error happens in the function u just call reject(error).

Answer (score -2):

You can change the function to an async function and await for it to return the value.

```
const handleCallback = async (childData) =>  {
        console.log(childData);
        return childData;
    };

    let childDataType = await handleCallback();
```

Comment: Thanks, Atul, but that had the same result. the problem is that childData is defined when it's passed as a prop but the function tries to return it undefined before the child can send the data. So it's basically just returning the value when the function is hit by the child component and it's returning the value before the child actually sends the value.

Comment: oh okay, so you can use the function to return a promise after its completed and then you can resolve errors too.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try to use the "await" expression?

```
 let childDataType = await handleCallback();
```

Check this for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Thanks, Pedro, but I've already tried that and it gives me the same result.